# Getting ANR in aftertextchanged while setting numbers to subscript in Android Edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a edittext which takes chemical equation as input. I attach html tags on text in aftertextchangedlistener. I am getting a lot of ANRs as Input Dispatching timed out in the code :

```
tv1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                int currentpos;

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)        
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        }


                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    try {



                        tv1.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        String s = editable.toString();
                        String s22=s.replaceAll("([0-9]+)","<sub><small>$1</sub></small>");
                         tv1.setText("");
                        tv1.append(Html.fromHtml(s22));
                        if (currentpos < tv1.getText().toString().length() - 1) {
                            tv1.setSelection(currentpos);
                        }
                        tv1.addTextChangedListener(this);

                        //SpannableStringBuilder  s= editable.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                          Log.e(e.getLocalisedMessage().toString());
                       }
                }
            });
```

All ANR point to the line

```
  tv1.append(Html.fromHtml(s22));
```

Can anyone help me with this?
And is there any better way to set subscript on the fly while entering text?

Stacktrace from Google Play (Both ANRs point to same line in code)

Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 (has extras) }

Input dispatching timed out

```
main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x737e0680 self=0xefefb000
  | sysTid=6357 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf41de4b8
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6694 stm=2163 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff524000-0xff526000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=

  #00  pc 0000000000018e50  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)

  #01  pc 00000000000b7d99  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+88)

  #02  pc 00000000003ec5e5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*)+308)

  #03  pc 00000000003ec481  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+8)

  #04  pc 00000000007933e9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+144)

  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Native method)

  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:786)

  at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.hasSystemFeature (IPackageManager.java:6177)

  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.hasSystemFeature (ApplicationPackageManager.java:712)

  at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.hasSystemFeature (ApplicationPackageManager.java:706)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.shouldBlockFocusForTouchscreen (ViewGroup.java:1333)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1206)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1234)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1234)

  at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.addFocusables (DrawerLayout.java:1936)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1234)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1234)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables (ViewGroup.java:1234)

  at android.view.View.addFocusables (View.java:11181)

  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus (FocusFinder.java:108)

  at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus (FocusFinder.java:80)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch (ViewGroup.java:965)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch (ViewGroup.java:967)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch (ViewGroup.java:967)

  at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch (ViewGroup.java:967)

  at android.view.View.focusSearch (View.java:10846)

  at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection (TextView.java:8717)

  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.onCreateInputConnection (AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView.java:189)

  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner (InputMethodManager.java:1690)

  at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput (InputMethodManager.java:1604)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5940)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:6059)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5876)

  at android.widget.EditText.setText (EditText.java:143)

  at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5833)

  at com.equationbalancer.MainActivity$4.afterTextChanged (MainActivity.java:1106)

  at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged (TextView.java:10745)

  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged (TextView.java:14241)

  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1262)

  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:574)

  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:504)

  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace (SpannableStringBuilder.java:502)

  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText (BaseInputConnection.java:849)

  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText (BaseInputConnection.java:199)

  at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText (EditableInputConnection.java:183)

  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage (IInputConnectionWrapper.java:341)

  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage (IInputConnectionWrapper.java:85)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7000)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)

  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:441)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: please add a pic of logcat

Comment: i added the log from googleplay, please take a look.